# Best way to reindex multiple indices in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am using Elasticsearch 5.1.1 and have 500 + indices created with default mapping provided by ES.

Now we have decided to use dynamic templates.
In order to apply this template/mapping to old indices I need to reindex all indices.

What is the best way to do it? Can we use Kibana for this ? Couldn't find sufficient documentation to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`_reindex` API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/docs-reindex.html#_reindex_daily_indices) which can also reindex multiple indices. It was specifically built for this.

Comment: Thanks Andrei , can you please give small example , Also please note .I want to reindex using java

Comment: I would start from this suggestion: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/reindex-java-api/45923

Comment: Ok .. , actually we are using AWS ElasticSearch instance , I guess there are some issues for support of transport client for AWS ES instance.

Comment: I have no idea how AWS ES does it. And you should have specified all these details in your post right from the start, not after me providing an answer. This is a poor quality post.

Comment: Sorry for that , but your hint i.e https://discuss.elastic.co/t/reindex-java-api/45923 , really helped ! Thanks again !!

Comment: Hi Val , @AndreiStefan  , needed some help for reindexing , I have posted a new question here :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863031/elasticsearch-painless-script-for-reindexing

Answer (score 4):

Example: Reindex from a daily index to a monthly index (August)

```
POST _reindex?slices=10&refresh
{
  "source": {
    "index": "myindex-2019.08.*"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "myindex-2019.08"
  }
}
```

Monitor reindex task (wait until is finished)

```
GET _tasks?detailed=true&actions=*reindex
```

Check if new index was created

```
GET _cat/indices/myindex-2019.08*?v&s=index
```

You can delete old indices

```
DELETE myindex-2019.08.*
```

Source:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html

Answer (score 0):

Bash script to re-index all indices matching a pattern: https://gist.github.com/hartfordfive/e507bc47e17f4e03a89055918900e44d

Answer (score -1):

If you want to filter some field and reindex it from index you can use this.

`POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "auditbeat",
      "query": {
      "match": {
        "agent.version": "7.6.0"
      }
    }
},
 "dest": {
   "index":"auditbeat-7.6.0"
    }
 }`